# How can I keep alive the connection of Apache Ignite all the time as a singleton on AKS?

Tags: ignite, azure-aks, .net-6.0

I'm using Apache Ignite on Azure Kubernetes as a distributed cache. Also, I have a web API on Azure based on .NET6.

I connect to Ignite with IgniteClient class. I made it a singleton but the connection closes in 5 seconds after starting.

I've tried

```
ReconnectDisabled = false
```

AND

```
SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
```

but both of them didn't work. How can I keep alive the connection all the time as a singleton?

Here is my configuration code of the Ignite;

```
public CacheManager()
{
    ConnectIgnite();
}

public void ConnectIgnite()
{
    _ignite = Ignition.StartClient(GetIgniteConfiguration());
}

public IgniteClientConfiguration GetIgniteConfiguration()
{
    var appSettingsJson = AppSettingsJson.GetAppSettings();

    var igniteEndpoints = appSettingsJson["AppSettings:IgniteEndpoint"];
    var igniteUser = appSettingsJson["AppSettings:IgniteUser"];
    var ignitePassword = appSettingsJson["AppSettings:IgnitePassword"];
    var nodeList = igniteEndpoints.Split(",");

    var config = new IgniteClientConfiguration
    {
        Endpoints = nodeList,
        UserName = igniteUser,
        Password = ignitePassword,
        EnablePartitionAwareness = true,
        SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    };

    return config;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this has to do with AKS networking and client configuration. Is the client in the same AKS cluster as the servers? How do you configure the client - a fixed IP, egress endpoint, something else?

Comment: Thank you, Pavel. The client isn't on the same server with AKS. But it has been configured with fixed IP.

Comment: In short, thin client should connect to a load balancer with session affinity enabled. Please see https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/azure-deployment for more details.

Comment: This is the document I followed the instructions for when I deployed the Ignite. I'm using the load balancer IP when connecting to Ignite with ThinCLient. But I couldn't keep alive the connection.

Comment: Do you have `sessionAffinity` enabled?

Comment: I didn't know the sessionAffinity property on service, I checked the document and I saw it. Thank you, Pavel. But all documents set sessionAffinity : None. I couldn't find how can I set the my client IP. I've tried like this {sessionAffinity: - ip: 51.105.113.xx} it didn't work.

Comment: I think it should be literally `sessionAffinity: ClientIP`, like in the docs.

Comment: I thought I need to write actual ClientIP, not a definition. I've tried it and so far so good. let me try this couple of hours and see it.

Comment: OguzKaanAkyalcin can you please let me know if the problem is solved?